# How do I run a java program through the console (command prompt)?

Tags: java, cmd, compilation, command-prompt, javac

I would like to test out this game by running it in my command prompt. I am able to compile both of the java files alone but not sure what to do from there. So far I've:

- Installed JRE and JDK
- Added the directory of my bin folder (***C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin***) to the "Path" Environment Variables (both **User Variables** and **System Variables**)
- Copied and pasted the Snake.java and Board.java into a folder called "javaprogram" on a separate drive (D:)

So far my inputs in cmd are:

1. D:
2. cd javaprogram
3. javac Snake.java Board.java

**What do I do from here?**

This is the link to the source code of the 2 java files. 
http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/snake/

Comment: as already 3 answered, you need to use `java` with the name of the *main* class (containing the `main` method), in that case its `Snake` - so try `java cam.zetcode.Snake` - but that all requires the correct folder structure and working diretory

Comment: Trying this, "Error: Could not find or load main class cam.zetcode.Snake" is the result. I currently only have the 2 java files in the directory, should I have the entire folder with all the extra files and pictures?

Comment: the 2 class files, generated by `javac`, must be in the correct folders - try [Managing Source and Class Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all you files in the directory **javaprogram**

I mean all of them : **Snake.java,Board.java,head.png,dot.png and apple.png**

Then you edit files **Snake.java** and **Board.java**

In Snake.java, remove package declaration at top of the file.

In Board.java, remove package declaration at top of file as well as edit the path of image files.

eg. `ImageIcon iid = new ImageIcon("dot.png");`

Once you have done all the above mentioned changes, use the below mentioned command:

`javac *.java` - to compile files

`javaw Snake` - to execute the program

Check whats the difference between **java** and **javaw** and **javac**.

If you are sending this game to someone just pack it in executable jar file.

Give my answer green tick :P

Comment: Okay I will try this now :)

Comment: For the compilation step, do I do "javac Snake.java Board.java" or "javac Snake.java Board.java apple.png dot.png...." or?

Comment: ha ha just compile java files

Answer (score 0):

After running 
    `javac filename.java`
You can run the following commande:
    `java filname`
Note that in the above commande filename doesn't take extension
If you encounter some errors, you try to remove 
    `package com.zetcode;`
at the beginning of each file and compile again and then execute

Answer (score -2):

`javac prgrm-name.java` to compile the code.

`java prgrm-name` to run the code.

Comment: What would the program name be? There are 2 java files I'm not sure

Comment: This is clearly wrong, and the comments to the question provide better answers.